# Masstransit consume fault without taking it off _error queue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

Hi I'm a noob when it comes to masstransit and RabbitMQ. I'm trying to implement a fault consumer that will just read from the error queue without actually consuming and taking the message out of the error queue.

I have a consumer and a fault consumer set up.

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, nameof(MassMailJobCommand), e =>
                    {
                        e.Consumer<MassMailJobCommandConsumer>(context);

                        e.Consumer<FaultConsumer<MassMailJobCommand>>(context);
                    });
```

And here's my FaultConsumer class

```
public class FaultConsumer<T> : IConsumer<Fault<T>>
{
    private INotificationsClient _notificationsClient;
    private NotificationsOptions _notificationsOptions;
    private ILogger _logger;

    public FaultConsumer(ILogger<T> logger,
                         IOptionsSnapshot<NotificationsOptions> notificationsOptions,
                         INotificationsClient notificationClient
                                       )
    {
        _notificationsClient = notificationClient;
        _notificationsOptions = notificationsOptions.Value;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<T>> context)
    {
        string exceptions = "";
        foreach (var ex in context.Message.Exceptions)
        {
            exceptions += $"{ex.StackTrace.ToString()};" +
                "\n=================>>>>>>>>====================>>>>>>>>==========================\n" +
                "======================        *END OF STACKTRACE*         =========================\n" +
                "===================>>>>>>>>====================>>>>>>>>==========================\n";
        }

        string message = $"Rabbit MQ Error:\n*Destination Address:* {context.DestinationAddress}\n*Original Message:* {context.Message.Message}\n*Exceptions:* {exceptions}";
        await _notificationsClient.Slack(message);
    }
}
```

It sends it to a slack channel. It works perfectly except I don't want the messages leaving the error queue.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Failed messages are *always* moved to the `_error` queue. That is part of how the transport works.

Creating a consumer for `Fault<T>` is a separate concern entirely, and consumes the fault event which is published by MassTransit when a message faults (and moved to the aforementioned error queue).

The fault event and moving the message to the error queue both happen as part of MassTransit.

Also, as a side note, I'd suggest putting your fault consumer on a separate endpoint (such as `fault-consumers`) so that fault messages aren't competing with the other messages to be processed. Receive endpoints read from the queue and dispatch the messages based upon type, so a bunch of faults could get in front of new commands.

Comment: Thanks for the side note. I understand that failed messages are moved to `_error` queues. That's fine but how do I read from the error queues when an error hits it, without consuming it and taking it out of the `_error` queue?

Comment: The only way you consume from the _error queue is if you add a receive endpoint on it - and I don't recommend doing that.